# redux init route with data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I go through of redux [real-world](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example and I would like to change couple of things. My app should fetch on app load initial data like list of items and clicking on a specific item should load details per item.

On the other side I would not like to nest different container to each other on routes this should call independent containers to manage app state.

How do I fetch data from store on app initialisation using Redux?

Comment: You can take a look at a small project I made to solve this myself: https://github.com/limelights/react-uniini

Comment: thanks for the example I will clone it to take a deeper a look

Comment: I cloned the repo and installed dependencies with npm install but will drop a lot of errors on gulp